# Strategy design pattern - populating a c++ class with an object

Tags: c++, constructor, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to implement a Strategy design pattern in C++.

I have an abstract class with no non-abstract method called ICookingStrategy:

```
class ICookingStrategy
{
    public:
        virtual int cook() = 0;
};
```

From this abstract class inherit two child classes: fastCooking and slowCooking:

### Child classes

```
class fastCooking : public ICookingStrategy
{
    public:
        int cook() { return 0; }
};

class slowCooking : public ICookingStrategy
{
    public:
        int cook() { return 0; }
};
```

### Context class

The point is, I want another class to be populated by an object instanciating either fastCooking or slowCooking, indifferently. Which means, an object instantiating ICookingStrategy.

But my problem is: I can't find how I can populate this receiving class. I thought in the constructor's arguments, but **when I try this, g++ gives me an error**:

```
class CookingContext
{
    public:
        CookingContext (ICookingStrategy* cookingStrategy):cookingStrategy(cookingStrategy)
        {}

        int cook()
        {
            this->cookingStrategy.cook();
            return 0;
        }

    private:
        ICookingStrategy* cookingStrategy;
};
```

In `main()`, I want to do instantiate one of the two child classes, then populate `CookingContext` like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  ICookingStrategy* cookingStrategy;
  cookingStrategy = new fastCooking;

  CookingContext cooking(cookingStrategy);
  cooking.cook();

  return 0;
}
```

**G++ error message on compilation is:**

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
CookingContext(ICookingStrategy* cookingMode):cookingMode(cookingMode)
                               ^
```

### So my question is...

What is the best way to make `CookingContext` being populated by the `strategy` object, instantiating either child of `ICookingStrategy`?

*(tried many different ones, and didn't manage to make it work)*

Comment: You'll need to take `cookingMode` by pointer or reference. Because `ICookingStrategy` being abstract it cannot be instantiated, and right now you're taking it by value which means an object of it would need to be instantiated.

Comment: You cannot initialize the class member variable if your constructor defines a parameter with the same name.

Comment: @MarkB [Wrong](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cf160c7d0d37483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor should take ownership of a caller-provided instance of one of the concrete cooking strategies, but needs to do so by pointer:

```
CookingContext(ICookingStrategy* cookingStrategy): cookingStrategy(cookingStrategy) {...}

ICookingStrategy* cookingStrategy;

int cook()
{
    return cookingStrategy->cook();
}
```

A destructor should be added to delete the cooking strategy:

```
~CookingContext() { delete cookingStrategy; }
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually putting `CookingContext(ICookingStrategy* cookingStrategy)` makes g++ generate this `error: Expected ')' before '*' token`... And if I put ')' after `ICookingStrategy`, g++ says `error: field ICookingStrategy has incomplete type`...

Comment: @Jivan: maybe you put `ICookingStrategy` into a header file that's not included in the file with the error?  Or, into a namespace?  Somehow, it seems the compiler isn't seeing the declaration of `ICookingStrategy`....

Comment: THANKS! Nice. I just edited my answer to fit a new version of the Main() function, because the old one was causing problems.

Answer (score 2):

The run-time polymorphism works on `references` and `pointers`, not on `objects`. Here you are using a `pass-by-value` for an `abstract class` in the constructor. You cannot create an object of abstract class. That's why the compiler is complaining!

Answer (score 1):

Answers by Simal Haneef and Tony D are correct.

The code should be like:

```
class CookingContext
{
public:
    CookingContext (ICookingStrategy* cookingStrategy):cookingStrategy(cookingStrategy)
    {
        cout <<< "CookingContext constructor has been called" <<< endl;
    }

    int cook()
    {
        cookingStrategy->cook();
        return 0;
    }

private:
    ICookingStrategy* cookingStrategy;
};
```